# $N_G(K) \cap H$ commutes elementwise with $K$

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a semidirect product of $H$ and $K$ such that $H \trianglelefteq G$. How can I prove that $N_G(K) \cap H$ commutes elementwise with $K$. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Serkan Thanks, I edited the question

Comment: Hint: What happens if you look at $hkh^{-1}k^{-1}$ with $h\in N_G(K)\cap H$ and $k\in K$?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Thanks, I got it. Since $H \cap K=\{1\}$, $hkh^{-1}k^{-1}=1$.

Comment: Yes, precisely.

Comment: Since you managed to solve it, I recommend that you add an answer with the details of the solution. This will make the question not appear unanswered, give you an opportunity to get feedback on the solution, and possibly even get you a bit of reputation.